# Using UCanAccess getting ERROR "unexpected token: table-name

Tags: ucanaccess

Related to earlier questions about "unexpected token"

I get the following error

```
         UCAExc:::3.0.3.1 unexpected token: $BRANDRAP
```

When I run the code below in the NB IDE

try 
      {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

```
    Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/DEV05/AmexDW/$TPMAIN.MDB");
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT [l BL Item Headers].[BL Counter], [l BL Item Headers].[BL A/C], [l BL Item Headers].[BL Entry] FROM [l BL Item Headers]");

    while (rs.next()) 
    {
        System.out.print(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.print(" :  ");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(3));
        System.out.print(" :  ");
        System.out.print(rs.getString(4));
        System.out.print("\n"); 
    }  
  } 
  catch (SQLException e) 
  {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return;
  }
  catch (ClassNotFoundException nf) 
  {
    System.out.println(nf.getMessage());
    return;
  }
```

NB. $BRANDRAP is a table in the $TPMAIN.MDB database but I'm SELECTING from
    the table [l BL Header Items]

Answer (score 1):

It's because the exception is thrown at the connection time. $ in table or column names wasn't supported in the previous versions because of a bug. The related 3.0.3 fix  didn't solve a particular case (when the table name starts with $). A complete fix will be in the 3.0.4. It will be released soon.

Comment: There are no "$" characters in any of the column names in the table [l BL Item Headers] but there are several other tables in the MS Access db $TPMAIN

Comment: As I said the exception is thrown before executing the query, at the connection time. So sorry.

Comment: After using another DB with no "$" in dbname and no tables with "$" and no columns with "$" as relevant lines of code below:

Comment: Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://S:/UAT/BSP_Reconciliation/BSPUPDATE.MDB");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM bspRecords");

Comment: Special character $ is already held except when it is the very first character.

Comment: Sorry for delay in answering.

Comment: When I use another Access DB that has no "$" in its table names or in the column names ....as in the code below:                                                                                                                                    
Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://S:/bspupdate.mdb");
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT Ticket FROM bspRecords");
        
  I get:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: This is another issue. It depends on the db size and it can be solved setting either a higher -Xmx or the connection parameter memory to false. See the ucanaccess web site for more details.

Comment: Adding "memory=false" as in the line below:                                              Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection                                       ("jdbc:ucanaccess://S:/UAT/BSP_Reconciliation/BSPUPDA‌​TE.MDB;memory=false") allowed the DB connection to be made. The connection took a long time though.

Comment: Notice that just the very first connection in the whole JVM life will be slow, the next ones will be instantaneous. Anyway there are several  parameter options (depending on the specific situation you're facing) to drastically drop down the connection time.